# Dataframe filter if value exist else return all

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to filter a DataFrame if a value matches else return every rows.When I try to filter using .isin in the code, it returns empty DataFrame.

```
My DataFrame:df
a_column   b_column
  1          3
  2          4 
  3          5
  4          9
```

If I try to filter with the codes like,

```
 df=df[df['b_column'].isin([7])]
 df=df[df['b_column']==([7])]
```

It returns empty DataFrame,
What I want as a output if I filter the b_column with 7 is,

```
My DataFrame:df
a_column   b_column
  1          3
  2          4 
  3          5
  4          9
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain scalar boolean by `|` for bitwise `OR` with `if-else` statement for test if at least one `True` by [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html):

```
m = df['b_column'].isin([7])
b = False if m.any() else True
df1 = df[m | b]
print (df1)
   a_column  b_column
0         1         3
1         2         4
2         3         5
3         4         9
```

---

```
m = df['b_column'].isin([3,4])
b = False if m.any() else True
df1 = df[m | b]
print (df1)
   a_column  b_column
0         1         3
1         2         4
```

Comment: Thanks.. It worked for me..Also In the same case, instead of returning the entire dataframe if there are no matches, I want to return a string "No Matches found". How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Venugopalsrinivasan - Then use `out = df[m] if m.any() else "No Matches found"`